# Kibana - search for "Googlebot" + "HTTP/2"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to ask for help.

I have Kibana 6.8.1 and asterisk search turned off. Inside are access logs data - similar to default Apache format. Each line is saved as a Message (don´t use grok to parse data to columns in this project).

I would **like to find all requests from googlebot which went over HTTP/2**.
T have tried to search "googlebot AND HTTP/2", but it didn't work (find out). Tried to escape / with / or . It didn't work.

Can you please help me to find all requests from googlebot which went over HTTP/2?

**Example of data (Googlebot over http/1.1):**

```json
{
  "remote_addr": "10.249.40.36",
  "time_local": "25/Jan/2021:12:55:30 +0100",
  "request": "GET /api/cs/v2/pois?leftBottomBounding=14.059467003565942%7C49.99607653436616&rightTopBounding=14.060915396433984%7C49.997224858777685&tms=1611575730422&zoom=19 HTTP/2",
  "status": 200,
  "body_bytes_sent": 186,
  "http_referrer": "https://www.****.?cena-od=0&cena-do=4000000&bez-aukce=1",
  "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Googlebot Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36",
  "http_x_forwarded_for": "91.214.158.2",
  "request_time": 0.033,
  "upstream_connect_time": "0.000",
  "upstream_header_time": "0.033",
  "upstream_response_time": "0.033"
}
```

Comment: Well, your data doesn't contain `googlebot` keyword at all. That might be one of the problems.

Comment: Thanks for reply - the mentioned example is for information only (as I wrote - example). There are lines with googlebot and http/2. I edited example data to contains googlebot and http/2, so we can move forward.
Do you know how to find the data using search input in Kibana?

Comment: So there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the query you have. Do you mind sharing your index structure? This will most likely unveil the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Can´t find what´s Index structure in Google. So, can you help? What do you want exactly?

Comment: Kibana is just a UI on top of Elasticsearch. When you run queries on Kibana, you actually query Elasticsearch index. In order to get that you need to open http://elasticsearch-url:9200/index-name, this will get your index settings and mappings. If you don't know your index name, try calling http://elasticsearch-url:9200/*, this should bring you all indices settings. Find the one where you store these logs and paste it here.